# NaN values arise after writing and reading a .sigmf-data file in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a Numpy array of complex values that I am preparing to write out to a .sigmf-data file:

```
# ISTFT
t_recon, x_recon = signal.istft(Zxx_unflip,
                                fs=sample_rate,
                                nperseg=NFFT,
                                nfft=NFFT,
                                noverlap=noverlap,
                                window=win,
                                boundary=boundary_istft,
                                input_onesided=onesided)

# Sanity check min, max, and lack of NaN values
print(type(x_recon))
print(np.min(x_recon),np.max(x_recon))
```

This output yields the following, so I'm comfortable that my array is a Numpy array, and has no NaN values in either the real nor imaginary part.

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(-0.6206440769919024+0.0022856157531386985j) (0.6165799125127172+0.112632267876876j)
```

Similar to the [SigMF documentation](https://github.com/gnuradio/SigMF), I then write this array to a `.sigmf-data` and an associated `.sigmf-meta` file:

```
# write those samples to file in cf32_le
data = np.copy(x_recon)
data.tofile('new_example.sigmf-data')

# create the metadata
meta = SigMFFile(
    data_file='new_example.sigmf-data', # extension is optional
    global_info = {
        SigMFFile.DATATYPE_KEY: 'cf32',
        SigMFFile.SAMPLE_RATE_KEY: sample_rate,
        SigMFFile.VERSION_KEY: sigmf.__version__,
    }
)

# create a capture key at time index 0
meta.add_capture(0, metadata={
    SigMFFile.FREQUENCY_KEY: center_freq,
    SigMFFile.DATETIME_KEY: dt.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()+'Z',
})

# check for mistakes & write to disk
assert meta.validate()
meta.tofile('new_example.sigmf-meta') # extension is optional
```

This produces no errors, and the array of complex values is specified by the `DATATYPE_KEY` of complex (`c`), float (`f`), and 32-bit (`32`). Then I read back in the file(s) I generated:

```
# Open file
collect_base = '/Users/me/'
sigmf_new_data_file = glob.glob(collect_base + '/*.sigmf-data')
sigmf_new_filename  = sigmf_new_data_file[0][:-5]
sigmf_new_signal = sigmffile.fromfile(sigmf_new_filename)

# Get the samples corresponding to annotation
capture_samples = sigmf_new_signal.read_samples_in_capture(0)

# Recheck the min and max of the read-in data array
print(np.min(capture_samples),np.max(capture_samples))
print(type(capture_samples))
```

Here, the output still reveals the array is a Numpy array, but now my min and max values are not only different, but they also have NaN values in the real parts *of the min and max values*. I know `(nan + nan*j)` values also exist elsewhere in the array.

What is causing the change in arrays? How can I remove whatever is damaging my arrays? Is the error occurring when I'm writing the file, or reading the file?

Answer (score 0):

The answer, it turns out, lies in the specific format of the values within the Numpy array. In the original question, printing the element type:

```
print(type(x_recon[0]))
```

returns

```
<class 'numpy.complex128'>
```

and the SigMF `DATATYPE_KEY` was complex float 32-bit.

But here's the rub: SigMF only has 32- and 64-bit options for complex floats (`cf32` and `cf64`), but Numpy doesn't understand 32-bit complex data types. So the only acceptable datatype between them is 64-bit complex float.

*However*, setting `SigMFFile.DATATYPE_KEY='cf64'` results in an error:

```
SigMFFileError: Unrecognized datatype: 'cf64'.
```

The fix, then, is to convert the Numpy array to `complex64` and set the datatype key to `cf32`. For some reason, this combination works, whereas the 128-bit to 32-bit conversion did not. On my system, this fix works.